# Как делать поиск файлов по маске в golang?

Tags: golang

Как в рабочей директории получить все файлы с расширением .txt ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

например, с помощью функции [`Glob()` из пакета *filepath*](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Glob).

---

пример использования:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
  files, _ := filepath.Glob("*.txt")
  fmt.Printf("%q\n", files)
}
```

---

```
$ go run example.go
["1.txt" "2.txt"]
```